# Extraction paragraph Number of text

Tags: vb.net

```
dim a as string = "select id from table"
```

I want, for example, the second paragraph as such :

```
second paragraph = "ID"
There paragraph = "from"
```

......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split string based on spaces in VB:

```
Dim words As String() = MyString.Split()
```

In C#:

```
string[] Parts = MyString.Split(new char[0]);
```

or

```
string[] Parts = MyString.Split(null);
```

Comment: There is no need to specify the Space char when using the Split method, a Split without parametters uses the Space char as default delimiter, then this returns the same result: `Dim words As String() =  MyString.Split()`